# How to retrieve an array of objects from a firebase realtime database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database.

[image]

I'm trying to iterate through each object and print "Name" value to the console.

This is my JS code

```
var scores = [];

var database = firebase.database();

database.ref().once("value", function(snap){
   scores = snap.val();
});

console.log(scores[1].Name);
```

From my understanding this is what happens.

snap = {rootKey : [array of objects]

scores = snap.val() = [{Name : Babara}, {Name : Josh}, ......]

scores`[1]` = {Name : Josh}

scores`[1]`.Name = Josh

**EDIT**

When I try to print whole array I get this.

```
database.ref().once("value", function (snap) {
    scores = snap.val();
    console.log(scores);
    console.log(scores[1]);
});
```

[image]

As seen here, I can't access objects inside the array.

Comment: Your function, being a callback, is being run _after_ `console.log` is run. What if you move the log statement into the callback function?

Comment: @csp713 tried this

Comment: `database.ref().once("value", function(snap){
       scores = snap.val();
       console.log(scores[1].Name);
    });`

Comment: `console.log(scores[1]);` this wont work because you can see the keys are unique id's

Answer (score 0):

try

```
database.ref().once("value", function(snap){
   snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
      scores['Name'].push(childSnap.val().Name);
      scores['Score'].push(childSnap.val().Score);
   });
});
```

Comment: `database.ref("/slo******").once("value", function(snap){
       scores = snap.val();
    });

    console.log(scores[1].Name);`

I tried this but didn't work as well.

Comment: Although this seems to work.

    `database.ref("4").once("value", function (snap) {
        console.log(snap.val().Name);
    });`

Comment: ok this is `slo****` your top node, i thought its a sub node. `database.ref()` is fine

Comment: It's the top node.

Comment: try `scores.push(snap.val())`

Comment: I deleted by earlier reply. Made a mistake.

Comment: Tried `database.ref("slo***").once("value", function (snap) {
        scores.push(snap.val());

    });

    console.log(scores[1].Name);`

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Comment: i think you need to loop through the result, because the result is a list. i updated in answer

Comment: i tried the exact updated code you typed. I'm still getting cannot ready property Name... error.

Comment: does `console.log(scores)` prints the data?

Comment: is this result happens when you do `snap.forEach`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Yh2Kk is for `snap.forEach`

I updated question details with new screenshot when my earlier code was used.

Comment: Hareesh can you please look at the EDITED code I put in my description. I seem to correctly store the array in scores. But objects cannot be accessed from the array using index.